# Symfony | Twig get field datas when display form

Tags: forms, twig, symfony

I have a simple form to filter a list in function of themes :

```
$builder
        ->add('themes', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'    => 'XXBundle:Theme',
            'choice_label' => 'image',
            ...
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
    ;
```

And in Twig I try to access all themes to do a specific render, in fact I would like to display Image (related to each theme : theme.image) instead of the theme.

I followed other solutions : [Symfony2 + CreateFormBuilder how to render an image in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057823/symfony2-createformbuilder-how-to-render-an-image-in-a-form)

But it doesn't work :

```
form.vars.value.themes / form.vars.data.themes (or form.themes.vars.value / form.themes.vars.data this is the same)
```

exists but are always empty. Because this is a new form. If I submit the form, it works form.vars are not empty anymore.

How can I get themes when I display the form for the first time ? I followed the doc (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-variables-reference) but I can't find what I want.

TY

Comment: Try with  `form.themes.choices`  (derived from choiceType)

Comment: Ty for your answer. "themes" is an EntityType, are you sure ? Cause I get "Method "choices" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist"

Comment: Sorry, i didn.t tried. So try with `form.themes.vars.choices`

Comment: It works TY. Btw where did you find this property "choices", in which doc ?

Comment: Is on the doc of the ChoiceType Field (the EntityType inherit from it)

Comment: can i post my comment as an answer so you can close your issue?

Comment: Thanks, Yes I don't know, try to comment with previous answer and I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the EntityType is a List of choices - form.themes.vars.choices. Its an array of ChoiceView, to get entity simply access public data property.

So use this property to access to the entities:

```
form.themes.vars.choices
```

More accessible attribute are listed in the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html).

Hope this help